# Transparent overlays in javascript gallery

Tags: javascript

I am using the code below to create a gallery from a link on my website. I know there is no was of fully protecting the images but would like to add a transparent overlay over the images. I can see methods of doing this by placing the images in a div tag and using css but am not sure that fits into the javascript I am using.

Has anyone got a means of adding an overlay into the javascript?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var mygallery=new simpleGallery({
        wrapperid: "simplegallery1", //ID of main gallery container,
        dimensions: [250, 180], //width/height of gallery in pixels. Should reflect dimensions of the images exactly
        imagearray: [
            ["gallery/img1.png", "", "_new", "&copy; me"],
            ["gallery/img2.png", "", "_new", "&copy; me"],
            ["gallery/img3.png", "", "_new", "&copy; me"],

        ],
        autoplay: [true, 2500, 2], //[auto_play_boolean, delay_btw_slide_millisec, cycles_before_stopping_int]
        persist: false, //remember last viewed slide and recall within same session?
        fadeduration: 500, //transition duration (milliseconds)
        oninit:function(){ //event that fires when gallery has initialized/ ready to run
            //Keyword "this": references current gallery instance (ie: try this.navigate("play/pause"))
        },
        onslide:function(curslide, i){ //event that fires after each slide is shown
            //Keyword "this": references current gallery instance
            //curslide: returns DOM reference to current slide's DIV (ie: try alert(curslide.innerHTML)
            //i: integer reflecting current image within collection being shown (0=1st image, 1=2nd etc)
        }
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a transparent div over your gallery.

You can do it like this :

```
.overlay {
    height : 100px; // height and width of your gallery
    width : 200px;
    z-index: 2000000!important;
    opacity:0.00001;
    position:absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/659hq/